Prove that the action of $\Bbb T^2$ on the Hirzebruch surface is Hamiltonian with the given momentum map
I am reading this thesis https://www.few.vu.nl/~trt800/theses/haroldnieuwboer.pdf
and on pag 11 there is  Example 2.2.3 that  I am trying to figure out.
Let $W_K=\{ ([a : b], [x : y : z]) \in \Bbb{CP^1} \times \Bbb{CP^2}: a^ky=b^kx \}$
This is a smooth complex hypersurface.  Let $j : W_k \to \Bbb{CP^1} \times \Bbb{CP^2}$ be the inclusion map, and set $\omega = j^∗\omega_{FS}$ with $\omega_{FS}$ the Fubini–Study
form on $\Bbb{CP^1} \times \Bbb{CP^2}$, which is proven to be closed
$W_k$ with its projection onto the first coordinate is a $\Bbb{CP^1}$ -bundle over $\Bbb{CP^1}$, and it is known as a Hirzebruch surface.
It is stated that the action of $\Bbb T^2$ on $W_k$ defined as
$(u, v) \cdot ([a : b], [x : y : z]) = ([ua : b], [u^kx : y : vz])$
is a hamiltonian with momentum map.
$\mu_k:W_k \to t^*\cong \Bbb R^2$
$([a : b], [x : y : z]) \mapsto -\frac1{2}(\frac{|a|^2}{|a|^2+|b|^2}+k\frac{|x|^2}{|x|^2+|y|^2+|z|^2},\frac{|z|^2}{|x|^2+|y|^2+|z|^2})$
I am trying to prove this using the definitions but no luck. I am restricting to the case k=1 for simplicity. I was recently introduced to this concepts and having a hard time proving this. The definitions are quite involved, probably the reason for which it was omitted I'd really appreciate if you could show me how it is done.
This are the definitions that I have from my course:


I haven't worked out the details, but in the hope this is helpful: Have you tried to verify $|x|^2/(|x|^2+|y|^2)$ is (up to an affine function/modulo normalization conventions) a momentum map for the circle action $u\cdot[x:y] = [ux : y]$ on the projective line?

@AndrewD.Hwang  I am having a hard time trying to do that. How would that realte to the problem? I am not sure I can split the problem into that and something else. I am specially having trouble with that ""  . What is $exp(TX_\zeta)$ supposed to mean? Dual? Pullback? Is it apply to the exp or to its argument? In any case I am not sure what it measn to apply to a curve and how to get rid of it

(i) My question was really a suggestion to think about/work out the simplest cases first (Fubini-Study forms and rotation in one coordinate on the projective line and projective plane) as a way of developing intuition about the definition before attempting the Hirzebruch surfaces (which are "made up of" projective lines). (ii) I read the star as pullback: $\exp(tX_{\xi})$ is flow along $X_{\xi}$ by time $t$. (iii) If it matters, there is a missing equals sign after $L_{X_{\xi}}\omega$ in the first displayed equation of the proof of Prop 6.3.2.

It suffices to prove that the torus action
$$\alpha : \mathbb{T}^2 \times (\mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3) \to \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3, \\ \alpha((u,v), ((a, b), (x,y, z)))=  ((ua, b), (u^k x,y, vz))$$
is Hamiltonian for the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3$, with moment map
$$ M_k : \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathfrak{t}^* \cong \mathbb{R}^2, \quad M_k((a,b), (x,y,z)) = \left( - \frac{1}{2}(|a|^2 + k|x|^2) \, , \, - \frac{1}{2} |z|^2  \right) .$$
(I'll let you convince yourself of the sufficiency of this.)
Weakly Hamiltonian. For $(U,V) \in \mathfrak{t} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, consider the function
\begin{align} H_{(U,V)} &:= M_k^{(U,V)} : \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{R}, \\ H_{(U,V)}((a,b), (x,y,z)) &= \langle M_k((a,b), (x,y,z)) , (U,V) \rangle \\
&= - \frac{1}{2}(|a|^2 + k|x|^2) U - \frac{1}{2} |z|^2 V .
\end{align}
To avoid working in complex coordinates (whose abstraction adds a further difficulty to the question), it's good here to use action-angle coordinates, i.e. to write $a = \sqrt{2 I_a} e^{i \theta_a}$, $x = \sqrt{2 I_x} e^{i \theta_x} $, etc. where the actions are $I_a := |a|^2/2$, $I_x := |x|^2 /2$, etc. Note that
\begin{align} H_{(U,V)} = -U(I_a + k I_x) - V I_z 
\end{align}
and
\begin{align} d H_{(U,V)} = U(-dI_a - kdI_x) + V (-dI_y) .
\end{align}
The symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3$ is
$$ \omega_{std} = dI_a \wedge d\theta_a + dI_b \wedge d\theta_b + dI_x \wedge d\theta_x +  dI_y \wedge d\theta_y + dI_z \wedge d\theta_z .$$
The Hamiltonian vector field associated $X_{H_{(U,V)}}$ to $H_{(U,V)}$ is implicitly defined as $dH_{(U,V)} = \iota_{X_{H_{(U,V)}}}\omega_{std}$, i.e.,
\begin{align} X_{H_{(U,V)}} =  U\partial_{\theta_a}  + kU \partial_{\theta_x} + V\partial_{\theta_z} .
\end{align}
Upon identifying $\partial_{\theta_a}|_{((a,b), (x,y,z))} = ((ia, 0), (0,0,0))$, $\partial_{\theta_x}|_{((a,b), (x,y,z))} = ((0, 0), (ix,0, 0))$, etc., we see this indeed corresponds to the infinitesimal action $\alpha$ in the direction of $(U,V)$:
\begin{align} \frac{d}{dt} \alpha((e^{itU}, e^{itV}), ((a, b), (x,y,z))) &= \frac{d}{dt}((\sqrt{2I_a}e^{i(\theta_a + tU)}, b), (\sqrt{2I_x} e^{i(\theta_x + tkU)}, y, \sqrt{2I_z}e^{i(\theta_z + tV)})) \\
&= ((Uia, 0), (kU ix, 0, V iz)) = X_{H_{(U,V)}}\, .
\end{align}
Hamiltonian. We need to prove that $\{ H_{(U,V)}, H_{(U', V')}\} = H_{[(U,V), (U', V')]} = H_0 = 0$. (The first equality here is the infinitesimal version of 'equivariance of the action', the second equality comes from the fact that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}$ is abelian, and the third comes from definition of $H_0$.)
For this, it is clearly sufficient to check whether $\{ H_{(1,0)}, H_{(0, 1)}\} = \omega_{std}(X_{H_{(1,0)}}, X_{H_{(0,1)}}) = 0$. This follows easily from the fact that $H_{(1,0)} = -(1/2)(|a|^2 + k|x|^2)$ and $H_{(0,1)} = -(1/2)|z|^2$ depend on different (complex) coordinates, and that different (complex) coordinates are Poisson-commuting.

Added: sufficiency of considering $\alpha$ and $M_k$. It is easy to see that the action $\alpha$ preserves (i.e., restrict to an action on) $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$ (the product of the unit spheres in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}^3$). We denote $i: \mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5} \to \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3$ the inclusion.
By definition, $\mathbb{C}P^{1} \times \mathbb{C}P^{2}$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$ under another torus action, namely
$$\beta : \mathbb{T}^2 \times (\mathbb{S}^3 \times \mathbb{S}^5) \to \mathbb{S}^3 \times \mathbb{S}^5, \quad \beta((r,s), ((a, b), (x,y, z))) =  ((ra, rb), (s x, sy, sz)).$$
We denote $p : \mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5} \to \mathbb{C}P^{1} \times \mathbb{C}P^{2}$ the quotient map.
It is easy to see that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute on $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$, which implies that $\alpha$ induces a well-defined torus action on $\mathbb{C}P^{1} \times \mathbb{C}P^{2}$, namely the torus action $\alpha'$ from the question.
The fact that $\alpha$ preserves $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$ also implies that the vector fields $X_{H_{(U,V)}}$ (which we know now are the infinitesimal actions of $\alpha$) are tangent to $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$; these vector fields are also invariant under the action of $\beta$ (since $\alpha$ and hence also the corresponding infinitesimal action commute with $\beta$). This means that the pushforwards of these vector fields to $\mathbb{C}P^{1} \times \mathbb{C}P^{2}$ are well-defined vector fields that we shall denote $Y_{(U,V)}$ (as they are the infinitesimal actions of $\alpha'$ along $(U,V)$ on $\mathbb{C}P^{1} \times \mathbb{C}P^{2}$).
It is rather easy to prove that $p^* \mu^{(U,V)} = i^* M^{(U,V)} (= i^* H_{(U,V)})$, hence (by naturality of the exterior derivative) $p^* d\mu^{(U,V)} = i^* dM^{(U,V)} (= i^* dH_{(U,V)})$. In other words, morally, we could say that each $\mu^{(U,V)}$ is the $p$-pushforward of $H_{(U,V)}$.
By definition, the (product of) Fubini--Study symplectic form(s) $\omega_{FS}$ on $\mathbb{C}P^{1} \times \mathbb{C}P^{2}$ satisfies $p^* \omega_{FS} = i^* \omega$ (where $\omega$ is the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3$). Morally, we could say that $\omega_{FS}$ is the $p$-pushforward of $i^* \omega$.
To say that $\alpha'$ is weakly Hamiltonian (with moment map $\mu$) amounts to proving $d\mu^{(U,V)} = \iota(Y_{(U,V)})\omega_{FS}$. For this, it suffices to prove that $d (i^*H_{(U,V)}) = \iota(X_{H_{(U,V)}}) (i^* \omega)$ (by, morally, $p$-pushforwarding the latter). However, since $X_{H_{(U,V)}}$ is tangent to $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$, this last identity is merely the restriction of the identity $dH_{(U,V)} = \iota(X_{H_{(U,V)}}) \omega$ (expressing the weak Hamiltonianity of $\alpha$ with moment map $M$) to vectors tangent to $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$.
To prove that $\alpha'$ (with moment map $\mu$) is Hamiltonian, again we only have to prove Poisson-commutativity (with respect to $\omega_{FS}$) of the different $\mu^{(U,V)}$, or equivalently that $\omega_{FS}(Y_{(U,V)}, Y_{(U', V')})=0$. Again, this question can be answered by lifting to $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$, i.e. by proving that $(i^* \omega)(X_{H_{(U,V)}}, X_{H_{(U', V')}})=0$, which corresponds (since the $X_H$s are tangent to $\mathbb{S}^{3} \times \mathbb{S}^{5}$) to the identity $\omega(X_{H_{(U,V)}}, X_{H_{(U', V')}})=0$ (which expresses the Hamiltonianity of $\alpha$ with moment map $M$).
The last two paragraphs thus show that it is sufficient to prove weak Hamiltonianity and Hamiltonianity of $\alpha$ with moment map $M$.

Thanks for the answer. Do you have a reference for the proof the sufficiency of the first part? I am having trouble proving that

@darkside I don't have a reference, although it is quite probable that the book 'Lectures on Symplectic Geometry' by Cannas da Silva covers this somewhere, and Audin's chapter in Audin & Lafontaine 'Holomorphic curves in symplectic geometry' also says a few words about Hirzebruch surfaces. But really, I recommend you think about the sufficiency. Hint: Restrict the moment map $M$ to the product $P := \mathbb{S}^3 \times \mathbb{S}^5 \subset \mathbb{C}^2 \times \mathbb{C}^3$ of unit spheres, and look at how it behaves under the quotient $P \to \mathbb{C}P^1 \times \mathbb{C}P^2$.

@darkside As a warm-up, following Andrew D. Hwang's advice, you might want to tackle first the prototypical example: prove that the circle action on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ given by $(t, [a:b]) \mapsto [ta:b]$ (corresponding to rotations of the Riemann sphere under the axis joining the north pole $[1:0]$ and the south pole $[0:1]$) is Hamiltonian with moment map $-(1/2)|a|^2/(|a|^2+|b|^2)$. It's essentially the same argument as the one from my answer: it suffices to consider how the circle Hamiltonianly acts on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with moment map $M = -(1/2)|a|^2$.

I am still unable to prove the sufficiency of the first part, I would appreciate if you could add details about this.

@darkside Done.
